# compiler error when i run my program

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
Dim st1 As String

'if txtmode 1 fetch record of id from database
If txtmode.Text = "1" Then
    'SQL statement
    openCon
    st1 = "SELECT Customer_name, Address1, Address2, City, Contact  FROM customer WHERE id=" & txtid.Text
    recSet.Open st1, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    recSet.MoveFirst

    If recSet.Fields("Customer_name").Value <> vbNullString Then
    txtCustomer_name = recSet.Fields("Customer_name").Value

   Else
        txtCustomer_name = ""
    End If
```

When I run my program, I get an error:

> compiler error : invalid use of property on txtCustomer_name = line

Why? and how can I solve it ?

Comment: If txtCustomer_name is a control, try txtCustomer_name.Text = ...

Comment: Agree with jac.  We need to know exactly how txtCustomer_name is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
If IsNull(recSet.Fields("Customer_name").Value) Then
    txtCustomer_name.Text = ""
Else
    txtCustomer_name.Text = recSet.Fields("Customer_name").Value
End If
```